# cannot find -lmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, solaris

I'm trying to compile a C++ program and one of the classes uses . g++ is not able to find the libraries would be my guess. The command i use to compile is -

```
g++ c1.cpp c2.cpp c3.cpp c4.cpp -o c4 -lm -lmysqlclient
```

c3.cpp is the file that needs mysql.h. This **works perfectly** on my local machine, but refuses to run on the server with the error

```
cannot find -lmysqlclient
```

I tried finding the libmysqlclient.so files on the server using the `find` command, I don't think they are present there

```
uname -a
```

reveals

```
SunOS opteron 5.10 Generic_139556-08 i86pc i386 i86pc
user@opteron 12:26:02 ~/c++/projname/
```

I realize that i need to link some libraries, but where and how?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you not install the libraries you need on the server?

Comment: No, i don't have the permission to do that.

Answer (score 17):

Whatever library packages u think is not installed can be installed using `sudo apt-get install`. But the problem is to find the right name of the package apt-get can understand. So how to do that ?! simple

use command : `sudo apt-cache search <filename>`

For eg.: in this case `lmysqlclient`

```
sudo apt-cache search mysqlclient
```

(remember to exclude 'l' from the actual name ,ie, mysqlclient and not lmysqlclient). 
This outputs:

```
libmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files
```

In the above `-libmysqlclient-dev` is the name that `apt-get` can recognize and solve our `cannot find lmysqlclient` problem

so now type: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` from interface.
After its done, try making your required file.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying [@SriHariY.S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401104/4675524)'s answer-

Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the MySQL client libraries? Can you look for it as

```
find / -name "libmysqlclient.so" -type f -print 2>/dev/null
```

Also, you can use the `-R` flag on linker to hardlink the libmysqlclient as

```
g++ -R/usr/local/mysql/lib ....
```

Or, you can export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64` as

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=$MYSQL_HOME/lib
```

Urko,

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 18 I used this command to find *a name* of required package for fixing this error:

```
apt search lmysqlclient
```

After this I installed missing package:

```
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev-compat
```

Comment: I tried to run `sudo /usr/share/one/install_gems` while installing Opennebula and I run in this issue. But when I installed `sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev-compat` it has fixed the problem in Ubuntu Live Server 18.04.